# Firebug не работает

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, greasemonkey

Здравствуйте, почему-то не работает firebug в firefox. А именно не показывает ошибки js в скриптах Greasemonkey. Firefox 30.0, Firebug 2.0.1, Greasemonkey 2.0

[Скриншот](http://higgs.rghost.ru/56856548/image.png)

Сценарий включен, пробовал перезагрузить firebug, пробовал `extensions.firebug.service.filterSystemURLs` менять на false.

Спасибо за помощь

Comment: А разработчики Firebug знают? Сообщите им баг. Мы-то чем можем помочь?

Comment: Ну недавно все работало нормально(пол года назад)

p.s. посоветуйте пожалуйста другое расширение для firefox для отладки js

Answer (score 3):

У меня перестала работать панель Firebug.
Почитав новости по этому событию — нашёл подсказку для возобновления работы **Firebug**: необходимо установить дополнительно еще одно дополнение **DevTools Tweaks**.

[Ссылка на страницу дополнения](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/devtools-tweaks/?src=api)